# Discord.js cant send message to channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

like the title says, for some reason i keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') at Object.execute (C:\Users\FieryTech\Desktop\SilverBot\commands\utility\apply.js:48:79)        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async Object.execute (C:\Users\FieryTech\Desktop\SilverBot\events\interactionCreate.js:16:4)`

here is the code for the file, please help, thanks

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyXsx.png)

Comment: You provided the error, not the code. Won't be able to help you with just the error, will need to see your apply.js code, near line 48.

Comment: @Liam i have the code there as an image, containing the whole file, this is because for some reason i couldnt put it in a codeblock because it would get out of it halfway through

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error is usually caused by trying to call the `send()` method on something that doesn't exist. If the client that you've defined is valid, then double check that the channel Id `'1198610544110882868'` which you're passing onto the `get()` method is valid as well, otherwise it would really throw that error you're getting.

Comment: thanks but i changed the code a bit and this worked using sqlite and sequelize, saving the ids in a file:

const guild = await member.guild.fetch();
const dbGuild = await Guild.findOne({ where: { id: guild.id } });
const whitelistChannel = await guild.channels.fetch(dbGuild.whitelistId);
await whitelistChannel.send({ embeds: [whitelistEmbed] });

and apparently that worked

Comment: That will work too. However, if you're going to apply the fetching of the ids whenever an interaction happens it can be slower since database queries can take a while. So I'd recommend fetching your ids only once, perhaps on the client ready event and then cache those Ids so you can access the ids immediately when you need them.